# DPM Disaster Recovery

Tags: active-directory, disaster-recovery, restore, scdpm

I'm using Microsoft System Center Data Protection Manager (2010, currently evaluating 2012) to backup my environment, and I have two questions about the disaster recovery process in the event of a total data center loss (no server or storage available, only off-site tapes).

I'm currently backing up to tape:

- The System State on the domain controllers.
- The DPM database on the DPM server.
- The databases on the Exchange 2010 server.

Every article I was able to found and read says the first thing you need in order to start the recovery process is the DPM database; so far, so good. BUT. Let's say my backup window starts at 21:00; the DPM database, being quite small, gets backed up in a couple of minutes. Then, at 21:30, the DC backup completes. The Exchange backup, instead, goes on for a couple of hours and completes at 23:00.

The backed up DPM database will contain *no information* about the DC and Exchange backups, because they completed *after* it was backed up to tape. So, in this scenario, will DPM still be able to recognize the backed up data and restore them?

The second question is sort of a Catch-22 one. In order to restore Active Directory, I need a DC backup; but, in order to restore a DC backup, I need a DPM server; **but**, in order to restore the DPM server, I need Active Directory (and no, DPM is not going to even *install* on a stand-alone server).

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question was actually easy: if a DPM server doesn't know about what is stored in a backup tape (because it's a freshly re-installed server, or because it's using an old copy of the DPM database), it can always re-catalog and import the tape, and then make use of the backups stored on it.

The second question still has no good answer, so I'm posting [a new one](https://serverfault.com/questions/424869/active-directory-disaster-recovery-with-dpm).